# Perform multiple calculations in one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have a spreadsheet that has 4 columns that perform a simple "if" based on some data entered elsewhere. Adjacent to each of those columns is another column that assigns a "1" or "0" depending on the value beside it. The last column displays the sum of these "scores"

Is there a way to eliminate the 4 "score" columns?

This is a sample row:

"5.2"   "1"  "4.7"  "1"  "5.0"  "1"  "65" "1" "4"

The formula in the "score" columns is:

=IF(AND(Match!$D$33:$D$1202>=minBflex,Match!$D$33:$D$1202<=maxBflex),1,IF(Match!$C$33:$C$1202="","",0))

The formula in the "total score" column (where I want to combine all of this) is currently:

=IF(C34=$B$18,-1,IF(C34="","",E34+G34+I34+K34))

This is in Google Sheets if it matters.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, in the case where all four scores are "1", you do not want to see the "1"s, but still want to see the "4" in the last column?

Your formulas and references are quite convoluted, as things like the sheet "Match" and the values "minBflex" and "maxBflex" are not meaningful. Also, it seems that you can forego a nested IF(AND()) and use an inclusive ISBETWEEN().

However, your formula will likely need to consist of a simple SUM() wrapper, and then test for the four individual cases assigning a "1" for success.

In code:

```
SUM(
  IF(
    ISBETWEEN(
      Match!$D$33:$D$1202,
      minBflex,
      maxBflex,
      TRUE,
      TRUE
    ),
    1
  ),
  // Repeat the above block IF() three more times with the needed range(s)
)
```

Comment: The ideal solution would be to have the "total score" column do all the work and just display the result (1, 2, 3 or 4)

Comment: Ok, then the above code example should work for you. You'll just have to repeat the IF() block three more times, and fix the four cell references.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your formulas are fine!
Your problem states that you "do not want to see the '1's"
Have you considered just hiding the columns with the formulas in them?
Select the entire column, right click, "Hide"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I could hide the columns, but I am trying to update/modernize the tool and find efficiencies.

Comment: I think the solution that eliminates the columns C, E, G, I, K would be a very cumbersome formula. It would be possible to write, but it would be impossible to read/debug afterwards. Which makes it unsupportable. I guess that is my way of saying that it would be less efficient. It is unclear to me whether it would be faster or slower, but making it harder to read, is a bad idea.